# drop_caches fixes AUFS, why?

Tags: cache, aufs

I have a file `test.txt` at:

```
./a/test.txt                    (1 KB, old one)
./unionWritableFolder/test.txt  (2 KB, should be overriding)
./unionMergedFolder/test.txt    (1 KB, old one)
```

if I do this:

```
echo 3 | sudo -k tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

the newest modified file on an AUFS `unionMergedFolder` will be the correct one:

```
./unionWritableFolder/test.txt
```

Otherwise it will keep showing the old file: `./a/test.txt`

It is like the cache is not being updated? I don't really understand what is going on. **Is there some way to make the cache work properly?** so I don't need to drop it all the time?

P.S.: I don't intend to stop using AUFS as it is very good to understand and use, very user friendly.

Comment: By the way, you probably don't need to say `./directory_name/file_name` — you use ``./file_name`` for a file in the current directory; otherwise, ``directory_name/file_name`` should work fine.

Comment: @G-Man the problem is that I need to access it thru `./unionMergedFolder/test.txt`, actually the application will look for that file, it doesnt know about the other directories.

Comment: But have you tried saying `unionMergedFolder/test.txt` instead?

Comment: @G-Man that would be on a terminal, with `./` or without. The application probably uses relative path and is failing. Anyway, using nautlius F5 I see no changes on the file, unless I drop caches, when also the application will access the new file.

Comment: Hmm, if writing to `vm/drop_caches` has any observable effect other than performance, that's surely a bug somewhere.

Comment: @Gilles mmm.. ubuntu 14.04 here, upgrading may solve it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to: 'Is there some way to make the cache work properly?' (well to actually make aufs writes work properly)

when mounting the aufs, it seems to ONLY work properly if we use `-o sync` toguether with br like in `-o sync,br="..."`

now it is finally working great concerning making write updates ready, even timestamps!

PS.: The problem still happens at ubuntu 16.04, making sync required.